# How to find the "configure" shell script in MacOS Catalina?

Tags: command-line, script

In order to compile Grace-5.1.25 I need to run configure first. 
But configure does not seem to exist. In earlier versions of MacOS I used configure several times. 
Does anyone know where I can obtain configure ?

Comment: There is no `configure` program.  What this is telling you is to use the `make config` directive prior to compiling and installing (`make install`) the program

Answer (score 1):

Delete the question!  I found "configure" in another directory.
Apologies for asking

Comment: If you could edit this to show where and how you searched, where it was found, I bet people would learn from this.

Comment: I had downloaded the source code for an application (xppaut), which included  a "configure" file as well as the usual README. I had been remiss in reading the directory listing for the source code.